# how to install gi module with Python 3.11

Tags: installation, pip, module, python-3.11

I install python3.11 on my ubuntu22.04, but when I import `gi`, show issue "`can not import gi module, ModuleError`"

How can I fix this issue ?

I try to install pygobject and some depends from google answers, but not work.